# How to test hbase mapreduce code?

Tags: unit-testing

```
class reduce {
    private HTable table = null;

    protected void setup() {
        table = new HTable(context.getConfiguration,"tablename");
    }

    public void reduce() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'd like to write unit test for above code, but I do not know how to mock the HTable, it always run error with (not find hbase-default.xml error..). I think it happened in new HTable(). Are there any methods to mock this object and pass it into reduce class?

Now I'm using JUnit, MRUnit, Powermock+mockito.

Comment: You might need more tags regarding unit testing to attract a better answer. Are you able to connect to HBase elsewhere in your program?

Comment: The reduce can be run in the deployment environment.There is no HBase environment in my machine, and I just want to run the unit test for it with some mocks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with unit test mocking, but the way your code is written now it looks like your application expects to find an actual running instance of HBase. I think the hbase-default.xml error is related to HBase configuration or the lack thereof. I can't help you with this post, but perhaps an article such as this one http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EasyMock/article.html will point you in a direction. I see other people on the internet talk about mocking frameworks.

Comment: Thanks, but it only introduces some basic skills.